# Google API Breaks Change Detector in Lazy Loaded Module

Tags: angular

I have loaded google APIs in my angular application and am using it to authenticate and connect and work with google services but it breaks the change detector and angular view stops refreshing changes from the component. It can be seen in the stack-blitz example below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgzrt2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.ts

What should happen here is when I get back from Google API Redirect URI the value should be true in the `example.component.html`

Answer (score 0):

You should get your Auth Instance and then try to grant access from it.
I create a copy from your project and editing it, check this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qskspm?file=src/app/modules/example/example.component.ts).

Please copy the **loadGoogle** function to your code and then test.

Comment: I've implemented and updated code using the logic you mentioned it is still not updating the value in the `view`